# Cannot create EmailSendDefinition with DeliveryScheduledTime property set

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, fuel-sdk

I can create the EmailSendDefinition fine, without setting this field, when I add it I get the following error:

"An error occurred when attempting to save the email send definition   object by calling stored procedure dbo.EmailSendDefinitionUpdIns."

Is the DeliveryScheduledTime not a valid property of the EmailSendDefinition?

Here is the body of the create request:

```
<ns0:CreateRequest>
     <ns0:Objects xsi:type="ns0:EmailSendDefinition">
        <ns0:CustomerKey>my_cust_key</ns0:CustomerKey>
        <ns0:Name>my_name</ns0:Name>
        <ns0:SendClassification>
           <ns0:CustomerKey>Default Commercial</ns0:CustomerKey>
        </ns0:SendClassification>
        <ns0:SuppressTracking>false</ns0:SuppressTracking>
        <ns0:SendDefinitionList>
           <ns0:CustomerKey>sendable_de_name</ns0:CustomerKey>
           <ns0:DataSourceTypeID>CustomObject</ns0:DataSourceTypeID>
        </ns0:SendDefinitionList>
        <ns0:Email>
           <ns0:CustomerKey>email_key</ns0:CustomerKey>
        </ns0:Email>
        <ns0:IsMultipart>false</ns0:IsMultipart>
        <ns0:DeduplicateByEmail>true</ns0:DeduplicateByEmail>
        <ns0:DeliveryScheduledTime>18:44:44+00:00</ns0:DeliveryScheduledTime>
        <ns0:MessageDeliveryType>Standard</ns0:MessageDeliveryType>
        <ns0:TimeZone>
           <ns0:Name>UTC</ns0:Name>
        </ns0:TimeZone>
     </ns0:Objects>
  </ns0:CreateRequest>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've not seen this done like this. You normally create the EmailSendDefinition and then Perform or Schedule it. A good example of scheduling can be found here:

[Scheduling an Email Send Definition](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/scheduling_an_email_send_definition/)

Comment: Thanks,  the reason I was attempting to add DeliveryScheduleTime, was because I couldn't get perform to work. So I was just figured, maybe it was because the DeliveryScheduleTime wasn't defined.